# How to implement automatic url detection like facebook? (Not how to implement url extraction)

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I got stuck on issue detecting url like Facebook. 
In Facebook when we type any url it automatically fetches url details. It checks input data in text area followed by space and then it fetches details of that typed url.

For example, I type

```
www.google.com
```

in my Facebook status update text area and when I press spacebar it will take input url and find its details.

Like this:

> Gmail: Email from Google
>      https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin...
>
> 7+ GB of storage, less spam, and mobile access. Gmail is email that's intuitive, efficient, and useful. And maybe even fun.

I have already implemented url extraction and gets all details from url like Facebook, but in my implementation I have a text area and one submit button. when user press submit button it will fetch details of inputed url if available.

I want to upgrade my implementation like Facebook.
I place my code here with, what changes I need to do? Please give me some tips/guidance.

My code:

```
<div>
<input type="text" name="url" size="64" id="url" />
<input type="submit" name="attach" value="Attach" id="attach" />
</div>

<div id="loader">
// Url content display div
</div>
```

Script Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#url').keyup(function () {
        //alert("something is here!!");
        if (!isValidURL($('#url').val())) {
            //                alert('Please enter a valid url.');
            return false;
        }
        else {
            $('#load').show();
            var a = $('#url').val();
             // some code for extracting url//
             }
          }
    });
```

`isValidURL()` to detect whether its url or not.

What changes I have to do so that it will find first entered text is url or not and if its url then only it will go further. ( How can I check text before spacebar)?

Answer (score 0):

You can ping the entered text and check the answer.